# ${BRANCH_NAME} hasn't replaced in git commit template

Tags: git

git version is 2.39.0,  git template has configed.

```bash
deepvision@ubuntu:~/source/repos/dv-detector/dv_ui$ git version
git version 2.39.0
deepvision@ubuntu:~/source/repos/dv-detector/dv_ui$ git config --list |grep template
commit.template=.gitmessage
```

`.gitmessage`file content:

```
# Description of the changes made in this commit

## Type of change
- [ ] Bug fix
- [ ] New feature
- [ ] Breaking change

## Related issues
- Fixes #ISSUE_NUMBER
- Implements #ISSUE_NUMBER

## Current branch
Branch: ${BRANCH_NAME}
```

but, ${BRANCH_NAME} hasn't replaced with current branch's name after i typeed `git commit`
[commit message editing in vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFda5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not do this for you.

If you would like to have something (not Git itself) do it for you, write yourself a "prepare commit message" hook as described in [the githooks documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).  The name of this hook is `prepare-commit-msg` and it must be located in `.git/hooks` or your configured hook directory.

You must write this hook yourself (or perhaps find one, but StackOverflow is not the place to go for recommendations of this sort).

Comment: Thank you, chatGTP told me that this problem is caused by git version lower than 2.9, I was cheated